# using Spacy to remove names from a data frame in Python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

I am working with spacy package v3.2.1 in Python 3.9 and wanted to understand how I can use it to remove names from a data frame. I tried following the spacy documentation and I am able to identity names correctly, but not understanding how I can remove them. My goal is to remove all names from a specific column of the data frame.

**Actual**

| ID | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| A123 | I am five years old, and my name is John |
| X907 | Today I met with Dr. Jacob |

**What I am trying to accomplish**

| ID | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| A123 | I am five years old, and my name is |
| X907 | Today I met with Dr. |

Code:

```
#loading packages
import spacy
import pandas as pd
from spacy import displacy


#loading CSV
df = pd.read_csv('names.csv)

#loading spacy large model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

#checking/testing is spacy large is identifying named entities
df['test_col'] = df['Comment'].apply(lambda x: list(nlp(x).ents))
```

**What my code does**

| ID | Comment | test_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | I am five years old, and my name is John | [(John)] |
| X907 | Today I met with Dr. Jacob | [(Jacob)] |

But how do I go from removing those names from the Comment column? I think I some sort of function that iterates over each row of the data frame and removes the identified entities. Would appreciate your help

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import spacy
import pandas as pd

# Test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A123','X907'], 'Comment':['I am five years old, and my name is John', 'Today I met with Dr. Jacob']})

# Initialize the model
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')

def remove_names(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    newString = text
    for e in reversed(doc.ents):
        if e.label_ == "PERSON": # Only if the entity is a PERSON
            newString = newString[:e.start_char] + newString[e.start_char + len(e.text):]
    return newString

df['Comment'] = df['Comment'].apply(remove_names)
print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
     ID                               Comment
0  A123  I am five years old, and my name is
1  X907                 Today I met with Dr.
```

Comment: Thank you so much Wiktor. This suggestion worked! I also came up with an alternative method that solved the issue. I will update the post with that as well.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an idea using the string `replace` method:

EDIT: Stripping parens off to see if that helps.

```
df['test_col'] = df['Comment'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace(str(nlp(x).ents).lstrip('(').rstrip(')')), '')
```

I typecasted the variables to help with the match, also not sure if it is a str or not. You may need to use an index, and loop it if there are multiple names found in a single comment, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Hi FlippinBits. Unfortunately that technique didn't work. The new column I get back still has those entities and are not replaced with the suggested replacement. I have to say that was a good suggestion! I thought it would have worked

Comment: I just noticed nlp(x).ents is returning matches in a tuple, it will take a bit more tweaking. It could be made more ugly with chaining string `strip` or `replace` methods, but I'd rather not lol I'll post it just for example's sake

Comment: yes you are right, it is returning matches in Tuples. I am trying another method - will post solution if it works. Thanks again